# how do i get rid of the edges sticking out or is there a better way of modeling the picture into card form?

Tags: modeling, edges

[image: side view]

[image: front view]

[image: edges poking out]

[image: picture in edit mode]

okay so I am attempting to model a 3d image into a 3d printable picture for a surprise gift for friend of mine who loves this character from Baldur's gate 3. i made a plane then added the image to it by adding a texture and then used the displace modifier and then and subdivided it till i got the desired amount of detail before creating a plane the exact same size as the plane i turened into a picture to make the sides smooth like a trading card when i extruded it out. but now its sticking out the sides of the picture and i am just wondering if there is a way to delete the parts that are sticking out or if there is an easier way to take the picture and make it like a 3d card?